# angular leaflet directive - bi-directional property for marker clicked

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I'm using the angular-leaflet directive and I want to know which marker in my marker object array was clicked. I know that there is some way to have a bi-directional property similar to center but for selected marker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first need to configure an `events` object on your `$scope`:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    events: {
      markers: {
        enable: ['click'],
        logic: 'emit'
      }
    },
    ...
```

And add it to the `leaflet` element:

```
<leaflet markers="markers" event-broadcast="events"></leaflet>
```

Then, watch for the event in your controller.  The name of the marker will be available via the `markerName` property of the `args` parameter:

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.click', function(event, args){
    console.log( $scope.markers[args.markerName]);
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/1NCbo2zqri9GgdQxeTxJ